# Jquery show/hide breaks sharepoint date picker functionality

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, datepicker, hide, show

I have built a custom new and edit form in sharepoint 2007 with jquery 1.11, that has customized line item style fields that I am showing or hiding based on a corresponding set of checkboxes. The jquery functionality is working fine, however now the date picker functionality from sharepoint doesn't seem to work on fields that I've hidden and then showed again. When I unhide the element by removing the style tag (display:none) the date picker works properly, but as soon as jquery touches it the functionality goes away. Below is an example of some of my code.

HTML

```
<tr id="trtohideshow" style="display:none">
<td>Line Item Label</td>
<td>Sharepoint date field with picker<td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
//Show hide line item referral info based on check box status of Services Interested In
$("#checkboxid").on("click", function() {
    if ( $("#checkboxid").is( ":checked" ) ){
        $("#trtohideshow").show("slow");
    }else{
        $("#trtohideshow").hide("slow");
    }
```

Comment: what is `#checkboxid`? Without quotes it looks like a variable but could be a typo

Comment: a jsfiddle would be helpful

Comment: Yes that is a variable in my actual script - I've changed it to quoted. I don't know how to load of of sharepoint's stuff into a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I solved this problem by getting away from using show() and hide(), and using a css class instead of setting **display:none** as an inline style on the TR.

I created the following CSS class:

```
<style>
.hiderow{
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
}
</style>
```

and applied the .hiderow class to each TR element:

```
<table>
<tr id="trtohideshow" class="hiderow">
<td>Line Item Label</td>
<td>Sharepoint date field with picker<td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then in the jquery function that adds/removes the class of the the row depending on :checked, I used addClass and removeClass on the TR element:

```
$(("#checkboxid").on("click", function() {
    if ( $(("#checkboxid").is( ":checked" ) ){
        $("#trtohideshow").removeClass("hiderow"); }else{ 
        $("#trtohideshow").addClass("hiderow");}
});
```

This code is specifically for the NewForm.aspx and only adds/removes on the **click** event - if you want to implement something like this on EditForm.aspx, you'll need to add the following function into $(document).ready as well as the last one so the rows that are already checked get shown when the page loads:

```
if ( $("#checkboxid").is( ":checked" ) ){
        $("#trtohideshow").removeClass("hiderow"); }else{ 
        $("#trtohideshow").addClass("hiderow");}
```

It's exactly the same function, but without the click event so chooses to remove the class or leave it right when the page loads. Hope this helps someone.